# Какая есть библиотека/пакет для массовой расылки сообщений пользователям бота в Telegram?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, telegraf

Есть бот, которым пользуются порядка 10 000 пользователей и нужно им всем разослать определенное сообщение. База chat id пользователей имеется.

В интернете я где-то видел кажется готовое решение  или статью по этой теме, но сейчас не могу найти. Какие есть готовые решения? Желательно нужен пакет для node.js.

Спасибо

Comment: Надеюсь вы не забыли что без желания самих пользователей получать сообщения от бота эти айдишники бесполезны?

Comment: @adrug нет, конечно

Comment: Можно воспользоваться модулем [`telegraph`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf): https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=sendmessage